# Solve the System of Linear Differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = Ay$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0  \end{pmatrix}$ and y= $\begin{pmatrix} y_1(t)\\y_2(t)\\y_3(t) \end{pmatrix}$

satisfy

$\frac{dy}{dt} = Ay$ ; t>0 ; $y(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1  \end{pmatrix}$

Then

1. $y_1(t) = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2}$, $y_2(t) = 1 + t$, $y_3(t) = 1$
2. $y_2(t) = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2}$, $y_1(t) = 1 + t$, $y_3(t) = 1$
3. $y_1(t) = 1$ , $y_2(t) = 1 + t$, $y_3(t) = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2}$
4. $ y_1(t) = e^{tA} y(0)$

Since $o$ is the only eigenvalue of A with mulitplcity 3 and eigen vector coressponding to zero is $  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0  \end{pmatrix}$ says $Q_0$

Now $(A-\lambda I)Q_1 = Q_0$, $Q_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0  \end{pmatrix}$

Similarly $(A-\lambda I)Q_2 = Q_1$,$Q_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1  \end{pmatrix}$

Since $B_0 = Q_0$, $B_1 = Q_1 +Q_0t$, $B_2 = Q_2 + Q_1t + Q_0t^2$

$y(t) = pB_0 + qB_1 + rB_2 = p \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0  \end{pmatrix} + q \begin{pmatrix} 1 +t\\1\\0  \end{pmatrix} + r \begin{pmatrix} 1 +t +t^2\\1 + t\\1  \end{pmatrix}$ ,where p,q ,r are constant

Now $y(t)$ satisfy the boundary value problem,we obtain $p=0, q=0,r =1$

$y_1 =1 + t + t^2, y_2(t) =  1 + t,y_3(t) =1$

My answer is not matching, Please tell me where did i mistake

Thank you.

Comment: You accepted no answers in fifty question you asked. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have an equation of the for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}}{\mathrm{d}t} =\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ does not depend on $t$, $\mathbf{x}$, or $\mathbf{y}$, it is always the case that its solution can be presented in the form 
$$\mathbf{y}(t) = \exp(t\mathbf{A})\mathbf{y}(0).$$

*Proof:* Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$: 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}}{\mathrm{d}t} =  \mathbf{A}\exp(t\mathbf{A})\mathbf{y}(0) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}(t)$$

Now, in your case, $\mathbf{A}$ is nilpotent (meaning $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbf{A}^{k} = 0$), since
$$
\mathbf{A}^{2} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\mathbf{A}^{3} = 0$. This makes it really easy to compute $\exp(t\mathbf{A})$:
$$
\exp(t\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{1} + t\mathbf{A} + \frac{t^{2}}{2}\mathbf{A}^{2}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t & t^{2}/2 \\
0 & 1 & t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $\mathbf{y}(0) = (1,1,1)^{T}$, then 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}(t) \\
y_{2}(t) \\
y_{3}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1+ t + t^{2}/2 \\
1+t \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Your mistake was attempting to do part (1) before part (4), which made the computation a mess.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = Ay$, and $y(0) = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, which can be expanded to get:

$\begin{pmatrix}y_1'(t) \\ y_2'(t) \\ y_3'(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1(t) \\ y_2(t) \\ y_3(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}y_2(t) \\ y_3(t) \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}y_1(0) \\ y_2(0) \\ y_3(0)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

So, we have 3 differential equations with initial conditions, which we can solve as follows:

Integrate $y_3'(t) = 0$ to get $y_3(t) = a$. Since $y_3(0) = 1$, we have $a = 1$, and so $y_3(t) = 1$.

Integrate $y_2'(t) = y_3(t) = 1$ to get $y_2(t) = t+b$. Since $y_2(0) = 1$, we have $b = 1$, and so $y_2(t) = t+1$.

Integrate $y_1'(t) = y_2(t) = t+1$ to get $y_2(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}t^2+t+c$. Since $y_2(0) = 1$, we have $c = 1$, and so $y_1(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}t^2+t+1$.

This shows that (1) is true and (2) and (3) are false.

For (4), note that $e^{tA}$ is a 3x3 matrix and $y(0)$ is a 3x1 vector. So, $e^{tA}y(0)$ is a 3x1 vector. But $y_1(t)$ is a scalar. Hence $y_1(t) \neq e^{tA}y(0)$, and (4) is false.

Note: This works nicely since $A$ is upper triangular. If $A$ is not triangular, you may have to actually compute $e^{tA}$.